# Use of 'it' in independent clause

Tags: sentence

- When there is object A and object B, the object A should be attached on top, the object B should be chained to the table, and a metal fitting should be attached to it (objectB).

When connecting independent clauses is it proper to use it to refer something mentioned in the previous clause?
I always get confused if I can use 'it' in a long sentence.

Comment: There's not really much *point* in using the pronoun at the end of your example, because you'd need to append **objectB** (or **objectA** or **the table**, whichever is *actually* meant) in brackets after it anyway, to resolve the ambiguity. But in ***other*** contexts, where there's no real scope for ambiguity, there's nothing wrong with using pronouns.

Comment: With technical writing/instructions such as this, it would probably be better to repeat objectB rather than use the pronoun *it*.   You should really avoid all possible ambiguities in such cases.

Comment: You need an editor and we don't do editing here. At least the rules say that.

Comment: Ok! Thank you! I'll avoid using 'it' if I think it's ambiguous. And I was not asking for editing.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing *improper* about using pronouns, just maybe *unclear*. As others have pointed out, if you had to add "(object B)" in parentheses to clarify the antecedent, then it's a place that a pronoun alone would be unclear. It has nothing to do with the fact that the sentence is long; it's because there are three different things (A, B, and table) being discussed, and especially because the intended antecedent isn't even the one that was mentioned most recently (table).

Comment: It's hard to follow out of context: When there is [an] object A and object B, object A should be attached to or at the top [?], object B should be chained to the table, and a metal fitting should be attached to the latter. This is really editing.

Comment: @Lambie (Oh yeah, I forgot: "on top" of what? Presumably "on top of Object B," but maybe that should be spelled out. Or maybe there are even more objects here!)

Comment: @Lambie But I'm taking the core question to be "Is it okay to use a pronoun in a long sentence," to which the answer is "As long as it's clear, go for it. If it's not, it's not about the length."

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes. You are right.It's not about length. What I wanted to say was, as you have said, the use of it in a sentence including more than one thing (objects A&B, table). I wanted to know if it's clear for people to understand that 'it' at the end is referring to Object B. And now I understood that it was ambiguous.